# Object not implementing method

Tags: ios, xcode, object, methods

If a message is sent to an object, but the object does not implement that method what is the next step?

Comment: Check if Object respondsToSelector method, refer NSObject Protocol Reference  for more info http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

Answer (score 1):

A crash, caused by unrecognised selector sent to instance.

Answer (score 0):

you'll get an exception. it should tell you what the selector (message) is, so check to see whether you've misspelled it when you call the method, or when you declare the method in the object's class.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `respondsToSelector:` on the object first to tackle that situation. That way you can handle cases where the object does not respond.

```
if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(method)]
   {
       //code here
   }
else
   {
       //code here
   }
```